# Logical operations

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic

So I'm working on an assignment, and I had trouble getting my code to work until I tried this:
instead of typing: 
`if (num != 0 and den != 0):`
to: 
`if not(num == 0 and den == 0)`
I also tried this:
`if not ((num and den ) == 0):`
 
I don't understand what the difference between these statements are. The second statement got it to do what I wanted, but I don't know why. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry for the vagueness, first timer here. 
So What im trying to do is:
One can show that:

(iii) if num != 0 and den != 0, then the two lines are not parallel and therefore intersect at a single
point.

Return True if the line segments intersect.

I got this from the textbook I'm using for my class. There's basically an equation that has a numerator and denominator and these are the statements made for them. Let me know if this is still too vague. Also, I'm using python 3. Thanks!!!

Comment: The first one only specifies that not both `num` and `den` can be zero. Although this is actually very confusing syntax.

Comment: Can you specify your requirement explicitly? Your second statement still may not work as your requirement expects. From first look, I guess because order of precedence having `and` executed before `!=`. You'd better to wrapped them around like `(num != 0) and (den != 0)` if you want to have `and ` executed last.

Comment: We have no clue what you want to happen since we have no concept of what getting your "code to work" is.

Comment: Are you talking about De Morgan’s Laws?

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited the question, also I haven't been programming that long, and don't know what De Morgan's law is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you want is a simple OR statement

```
if num or den:
```

which matches the truthiness of your chosen statement.

```
>>> def test(num, den):
...     print(bool(num or den), 'num or den')
...     print(bool(not(num == 0 and den == 0)), 'not(num == 0 and den == 0)')
...     print(bool(num != 0 and den != 0), '(num != 0 and den != 0)')
...     print(bool(not ((num and den ) == 0)), 'not ((num and den ) == 0)')
... 
>>> 
>>> test(0, 0)
False num or den
False not(num == 0 and den == 0)
False (num != 0 and den != 0)
False not ((num and den ) == 0)
>>> 
>>> test(0, 1)
True num or den
True not(num == 0 and den == 0)
False (num != 0 and den != 0)
False not ((num and den ) == 0)
>>> 
>>> test(1, 0)
True num or den
True not(num == 0 and den == 0)
False (num != 0 and den != 0)
False not ((num and den ) == 0)
>>> 
>>> test(1, 1)
True num or den
True not(num == 0 and den == 0)
True (num != 0 and den != 0)
True not ((num and den ) == 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

What your code does:

- The first piece of code checks if both values are unequal to 0. If so, it runs.
- The second checks if both values are equal to 0, and subsequently inverts that. In other words, it runs when at least one of `num` and `den` is unequal to 0, though the other may still be 0.
- The third compares the truth values of `num` and `den` (see below). The logical AND of this is then compared to 0, and then inverted. In other words, this runs when both `num` and `den` have a truthy value, which should result in the same behaviour as the first piece of code. Since this depends on truthy/falsy values rather than explicit comparison, I wouldn't recommend this - it may have some unexpected results for some data types.

Regarding truthy/falsy values:

- Integers and floats are falsy if they are equal to 0 or 0.0, respectively. Otherwise, they are truthy.
- List, dicts, and strings are falsy if they are empty (i.e. `[]`, `{}` or `""`, and truthy otherwise.
- `None` is always falsy.
- From my tests, functions (the actual functions themselves - the results are compared depending on their own datatype) are always truthy.

When testing on my machine, (1) and (3) are `True` when `num` and `den` are both non-zero and `False` otherwise. (2) is `True` when `num`, `den` or both are non-zero, and `False` otherwise.

From what Nelson said in the comments, as far as I know and could test `!=` takes precedence over `and`, so that shouldn't cause issues.

All of the above was checked on Python 2.7. I cannot give guarantees that it works the same for Python 3.

<strike>If you would like more help, you might want to put some more information regarding what your input and your expected output is.</strike>

Though your first and last approach should work on python 2.7, since you report the first one doesn't it may indeed have to do with operation precedence. You should be able to fix this by using

`if (num != 0) and (den != 0):`

That should execute if and only if both are non-zero.